# Welcoming new members not working with discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I'm trying to setup a simple discord.py enabled bot and having trouble welcoming new members. I have the following code and when a new member joins, the bot is able to process the default welcome message Discord sends but doesn't process anything in the on_member_join() function. I've enabled intents within Discord (both gateway and member) and still can't figure out why it won't process a new member joining. I've also tested with a brand-new created member and still won't trigger.

```
import discord

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready(): # When ready
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    print('Someone new!')
    await member.send("Welcome")

@client.event
async def on_message(message): # On every message
    if message.author == client.user: # Cancel own message
        return

    if message.content.startswith('?'):
        await message.channel.send('Command')

client.run(DISCORD_TOKEN)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not related to using `Client` instead of `Bot`.

You created the `intents` variable, but you're never using it. You're supposed to pass it into your `discord.Client()`, which you aren't doing, so the `members` intent will always be disabled.

```py
# Original question
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

client = discord.Client()  # <-- You're not passing intents here! The variable is never used so intents are disabled
```

That's also why your answer fixes it: because you're actually *using* your intents (`...intents=intents...`).

```py
# Your "fix"
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "!", intents = intents)  # <-- Notice the intents
```

Using `discord.Client` or `commands.Bot` has no influence on this: `commands.Bot` *without* passing intents wouldn't do anything either.

```py
# This would cause the exact same issue, because intents aren't used
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "!")
```

Passing your intents into the `Client` would also work, just like that fixes the problem for your `Bot`.

```py
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
```

Comment: Such a simple mistake and answer. Thanks for breaking it down, I marked this as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: See answer. Changing the below correctly passed intents (with members = True) to the bot.

Unsure why but I needed to use bot commands in order to resolve the issue.

Added:

```
from discord.ext import commands
```

and changed

```
client = discord.Client()
```

to

```
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "!", intents = intents)
```

I think this is what was required to 'fully enable' intents, but I'm not fully sure why this corrected the issue.

Comment: first thing if you coding a bot you should always use commands.Bot and if you use on_member_join you have to have the member intents and without it, you wouldn't get a request from discord saying that a new member joined to read more [click here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=intents#discord.Intents)

Comment: The issue isn't corrected because you're using `Bot` instead of `Client`, but because you weren't using your intents. I've posted an answer explaining why this fixed it.

Comment: @yotamrec "you should always use commands.Bot" - *why?* What's the purpose of `discord.Client` then? It's just personal preference what you use, it's not required.

Comment: @yotamrec Why are bot commands preferred over client? My intent was to start simply and incrementally get to more advanced commands, but is there advantages to starting with bot commands?